# How to reuse effectively Django models

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 type of Products , 1 is Product and 1 is sub product (child of product) but it will use same attribute  of product .

so my product table is like

```
 class Activity(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=False, blank=False)
    filed1 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=False, blank=False)
    filed2 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=False, blank=False)
```

and now it have like 4 tables of its properties for example I will paste 2 here.

```
class workinfDatDates(models.Model):
   agenda = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   Date = models.DateField()
```

and

```
class BlockedDates(models.Model):
   agenda = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   blockDate = models.DateField()
```

Now Sub Product is child of it like

```
  class SubActivity(models.Model):
        activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        subName = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=False, blank=False)
```

it should have same attributes like block dates and working dates etc . Now I should create new tables for it ? or is there any good way to use by including something to already defined tables ?

**EDIT**

My Activity table have so many extra fileds which I don't want to use like  filed1,field2,field3 etc

Comment: You could have a look at multi table inheritance : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance

Comment: yes I had @TimothéDelion  but i have foreign keys here aswell. how I can tackle them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using ForeignKey, you could use [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) :

```
class SubActivity(Activity):
        subName = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=False, blank=False)
```

This way, SubActivity **is** an activity, but with extra fields

Comment: just one confusion here . how I will differentiate them like its category or subCategory and how I will filter them ?

Comment: Sub Category will always a child

Comment: Two options to differentiate : `isinstance(obj, SubCategory)` or using a field `type` in `SubCategory` model, if you want to handle several types in a single `SubCategory` model (very relevant if they have strict similar behaviour, except for very little things)

Comment: No Activity have extra things , images etc and so many stuff . while subActivity just share its attributes just  which are in reference table .

Comment: Actually case is reverse , SubCategory have less fields but Same attribute tables like I shared . Now guide plz

Comment: I think you mis-understand the multi-table inheritance concept. We do not talk about two distinct tables, but one which is an "extra table" for the previous one. Maybe, **abstract inheritance** is more suited. But anyway, I think you are looking for inheritance mechanism

Comment: Actually, in a inheritance perspective, `Activity` should contain all the fields that are common for **all** you activities and subactivities. And you define as many `SubActivity(Activity)` children that you need. One could be `ClassicalActivity(Activity)`, with you so-many fields.

Comment: yes I was thinking same , but now that part is in working , I can't change I just have to append . in case what thing is best ?  I think I should  Do Inheritance just for attributes , like 5 new attributes tables .

Comment: Even if in production, you can make DB migrations (but you're right : it is not easy at all, but sometimes you have no choice). Otherwise, it is another question...

Comment: I make model as you suggested now I getting  reference errors on insertion :(